# use parameter as output in c

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory, pass-by-reference

I want to pass a pointer to a function as a output and initialize it in the function so that I can use it in the main function. This is my code to do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef const struct _txmlAttribute
{
 /** The namespace URL of the attribute qname, or NULL for no qualifier. */
  char *  ns;
} txmlAttribute;

int func(txmlAttribute* attrs, txmlAttribute** attrsarr, txmlAttribute*** arr){
    int i;

txmlAttribute tattrs[] = {{"ssa"},{"ss"}};
printf("sizeof(tattrs): %d \n", sizeof(tattrs));
printf("sizeof(txmlAttribute): %d \n", sizeof(txmlAttribute));
attrs=  malloc(2*sizeof(txmlAttribute));
printf("sizeof(attrs): %d \n\n", sizeof(attrs));

for(i=0;i<sizeof(tattrs)/8;i++){
    printf("tattrs[%d]: %s \n", i, tattrs[i].ns);
    memcpy((void*)&attrs[i],(const void*)&tattrs[i],sizeof(txmlAttribute));       
}
printf("\n\n");
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("attrs[%d]: %s \n", i,attrs[i].ns);
}
printf("\n\n");
printf("sizeof(attrs): %d \n\n", sizeof(attrs));
return 0;
}
main()
{
   txmlAttribute*** arr;
   txmlAttribute** attrsarr;
   txmlAttribute* attrs;
   printf("main: sizeof(attrs) : %d \n\n", sizeof(attrs));
   func(attrs, attrsarr, arr);
   //printf("main: attrs: %s\n",attrs[0].ns);

}
```

But there is two problems: 
1. As I have printed the size of passed pointer it is still 8 while I expected to be 16.
2. When I want to use this pointer out of main I receive a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

I am using gcc to compile my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef const struct _txmlAttribute {
    char *  ns;
} txmlAttribute;

int func(txmlAttribute **attrsarr) {
    txmlAttribute tattrs[] = {{"ssa"},{"ss"}};
    if(NULL==(*attrsarr =  malloc(sizeof(tattrs))))
        return 0;
    memcpy((void*)*attrsarr, tattrs, sizeof(tattrs));//const !
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    txmlAttribute *attrsarr;
    func(&attrsarr);//update const object!
    printf("main: attrs1: %s\n", attrsarr[0].ns);
    printf("main: attrs2: %s\n", attrsarr[1].ns);
    free((void*)attrsarr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Now I really understand what to do for call by reference in c :) @BLUEPIXY